# Cannot resolve symbol R after adding another xml file to my project

Tags: android, xml

As the title say , i was using only one xml file on my project **activity_maps** ,
and everything was working fine , but after adding **info_window.xml** , the symbol R became red and i don't know why , i tried rebuilding project and nothing happened.

This is my **activity_maps.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MapActivity" >

     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my **info_window.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sefleticon"/>

    <linearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/tv_place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/tv_men"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/tv_women"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/tv_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </linearLayout>

</linearLayout>
```

The both of the xml files are in res/layout

Comment: r? the stats language?

Comment: the reason  the symbol R became red  is because there is some error in your xml files, and if there are any error in your xml file then your whole project will not be build properly..I guess in your case check for any resource files are missing or not...try to clean the whole project and rebuild it again...best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second Xml to :

Change  **linearLayout** to *LinearLayout*

And in your TextView's change **android:id="@id/your_id"** to **android:id="@+id/your_id"**

Answer (score 1):

Change `id="@id"` with `id="@+id"` like this:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_place" <!--add +id-->
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**edit:**

and like Nikhil Verma said, change LinearLayout with upcase on two places.